# GUI with Serial Communication C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface, serial-communication

I am new to C# and Visual Studio. I have built a GUI to choose the COM port from a  MenuStrip in Visual Studio 2013. What I want to know is how can I connect this with serial port communication.

Should I use a another class for serial communication? Or can I do it in the same class? How can it be programmed?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
namespace exo_new
{
public partial class rehab : Form
{
    public rehab()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void conndToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void cOM1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cOM1ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
        cOM2ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
        cOM3ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
        cOM4ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
        cOM5ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
        cOM6ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
        cOM7ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
        cOM8ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
        cOM9ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
        cOM10ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
    }

    private void cOM2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cOM2ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
        cOM1ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
        cOM3ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
        cOM4ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
        cOM5ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
        cOM6ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
        cOM7ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
        cOM8ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
        cOM9ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
        cOM10ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`System.IO.SerialPort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx) class to program the serial port from a .NET application. (The link is to the MSDN documentation for the class, which includes an example program.) If you want more help than that you'll need to provide some of your code and more of an explanation of what you want to do, and when. (For example, user clicks button X and you want to send message Y...)

**UPDATE:** Thanks for sharing your code so far. Here is how I would implement a simple solution based on what you've started with:

```
public partial class rehab : Form
{
    private string portName = "COM1";
    private const int baudRate = 9600;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //TODO: Simplify your UI by dynamically creating the COM port names.
        //      Get the list of available ports on the computer via the following:
        //var portNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

        // Call this to initially mark 'COM1' as checked.
        UpdatePortCheckmarks();
    }

    private void conndToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textToSend = this.textBox1.Text;

        // Use a try-catch block to log any exceptions that occur.
        try
        {
            // Use a using block to close and dispose of the serial port
            // resource automatically. Also, note that the SerialPort
            // constructor takes the port name and baud rate here.
            // There are also overloads that let you pass the number of
            // data bits, parity, and stop bits, if needed.
            using (var serialPort = new SerialPort(portName, baudRate))
            {
                // Open the port before writing to it.
                serialPort.Open();

                // Send the content of the textbox (with a newline afterwards).
                serialPort.WriteLine(textToSend);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // You could also use MessageBox.Show. Console.WriteLine will
            // display errors in your debugger's output window.
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void cOM1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        portName = "COM1";
        UpdatePortCheckmarks();
    }

    private void cOM2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        portName = "COM2";
        UpdatePortCheckmarks();
    }

    // .. and so on for each additional port menu item (COM3 through COM10)

    // This method lets you share the code for updating the checkmarks on
    // the menu items, so your form code will be cleaner.
    private void UpdatePortCheckmarks()
    {
        cOM1ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = portName == "COM1";
        cOM2ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = portName == "COM2";
        cOM3ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = portName == "COM3";
        cOM4ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = portName == "COM4";
        cOM5ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = portName == "COM5";
        cOM6ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = portName == "COM6";
        cOM7ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = portName == "COM7";
        cOM8ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = portName == "COM8";
        cOM9ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = portName == "COM9";
        cOM10ToolStripMenuItem.Checked = portName == "COM10";
    }
}
```

I've included a 'TODO' comment as a suggestion on how you can further improve your code, but that's optional (and should be a new question if you do have any questions about it).

Comment: Thank u very much. From the user interface the user selects any port, that port is used to connect the computer. And then user clicks on the "connect". And the message will be sent.

Comment: Thank you so much..I have some problems in "TODO". I'll post it as a new question.

Comment: Lars I have a problem in this again..Should I post it as new question? When I select a COM port and then click connect it says "COM1" not found..Even i clicked on COM2 it says "COM1"

Comment: If the code I provided answered your original question, then it's probably best to ask a new one and include the updated code that you have now. And by the way, I saw your other question - don't assume that people will read your other questions to find out the context! Almost no one takes the time to do that. :)